# Convert date time string in PHP

Tags: php, strtotime

I have a Date/Time string from facebook graph that i need to convert to a readable date time.

2010-09-17T04:07:36+0000

How can I format it to GMT+8 using php to look like this below.

17 September at 12:07

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo date('j F \a\t H:i', strtotime('2010-09-17T04:07:36+0000'));
```

References: [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Set your timezone with [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) for correct conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get Date object using

$date_object = **date_create**('2010-09-17T04:07:36+0000');